# When I run Tomcat, the browser shows this error even though the HTML page is written correctly

Tags: java, tomcat

HTTP Status 404 – Не найдено
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.71

1. I cleared the cache of the browser
2. I opened and reinstalled Tomcat
3. Even if I close and open old projects and open new ones

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyGpl.png)

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://localhost:8080/yourAppName/` ?

Comment: When you start tomcat, try to see what happens in the console output or take a look into log file included in path <tomcat_home>/logs. Highly likely you will find an exception, which means something went wrong in startup process or when deploying a webapp.

Comment: try with 9.0.69 or 9.0.70 to see if it is the 9.0.71 issue. I saw some bug reports related to 9.0.71 now